# Implementing interfaces and extending classes in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with the following situation:

```
public static SomeClass<? extends Object, ? extends Object> method(AClass<? extends Object, ? extends Object> obj) {
        StaticClass.instance().field = new SomeAnotherClass<???, ???>(someObj);
}
```

How do i get generic dataType for SomeAnotherClass ?

Note: SomeClass and SomeAnotherClass implements the same interface that has 2 generic data types.

Comment: use names like T U V instead of question marks. Btw, any class extends Object...

Comment: The problem is that my StaticClass has a field: "private SomeAnotherClass<? extends Object, ? extends Object> field;" to keep the refference to the created object.